# Why does using new() on an object not get included in the memory profiling file in Go?

Tags: go, profiling, allocation, memory-profiling

This is the code I am profiling:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

type T struct {
    a int
    b int
}

func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    Add(1, 2)
}

func (t *T) Add() int {
    return t.a + t.b
}

func Add(a, b int) *T {
    t := new(T)
    t.a = a
    t.b = b
    return t
}
```

I ran the test using:

```
go test -memprofile mem.prof abc_test.go
```

But I can't find any allocation in the profiling file:

```
$ go tool pprof --alloc_objects main.test mem.prof
File: main.test
Type: alloc_objects
Time: Jul 9, 2018 at 9:40am (UTC)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof) top
Showing nodes accounting for 0, 0% of 0 total
  flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
```

Is there something wrong? To my understanding, the line `t:= new(T)` will cause an allocation.

Comment: `pprof` is a sampling profiler. Allocating 16 bytes is not going to get sampled when the default threshold is 512Kb.

Answer (score 0):

First of all is better if you split your test and core function into two file.
By that I mean in your `main.go` file should have

```
package main

type T struct {
    a int
    b int
}

func (t *T) Add() int {
    return t.a + t.b
}

func Add(a, b int) *T {
    t := new(T)
    t.a = a
    t.b = b
    return t
}
```

and `main_test.go`

```
package main

import "testing"

func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    Add(1, 2)
}
```

Then to resolve your anserw. Memprofiling is build into `bench` tool https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/ so you need to run your pprof profiling by using

`go test -memprofile mem.prof -bench .`

As you can see there was `-bench` flag missing in your command

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the allocation still remains unseen using the steps you provided.